# Correct way of freeing memory in a vector of pointers? (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a homework problem, in which I have a `class Student`, and a vector of pointers to `Student` objects, which is a member field in the Student class:

```
vector<Student*> vectorName;
```

In order to do correct(?) memory management, I declared the destructor in the Student class like this

```
Student::~Student() {
  for(int i=0; i<vectorName.size(); i++){
    delete vectorName.at(i);
  }
}
```

Does this **really** free the memory correctly from the heap, or is there a better way?

Comment: If everyone stopped using pointers, C++ wouldn't really be a lot worse for it, but StackOverflow traffic would plummet.

Comment: That depends. Are the students in the vector shared with other students? Can you copy students?

Comment: Use `for (auto* ptr : vectorName)` instead, or ideally use `vector<Student>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - yes, but then Java programmers would be scared of C++.

Comment: @Pete Becker: Aren't they already?

Comment: This is in the destructor of the very class that is also also being held-by-pointer in the vectorName vector. This screams to me that something may be amiss in your design. Ex. is it possible the students  pointed to by that vector have *this* student in *their* vectorName collections? You may want to bring a little clarification to this before assuming everyone saying "yes, delete it" is right.

Comment: @WhozCraig if there is a loop in reference even without dealing with pointer deletion trouble is awating him.

Comment: is it possible that `studentA` is in `studentB` list, and `studentB` is in `studentA` list??

Comment: Remember to make sure all the pointers in the vector are first initialized to NULL (preferably in the Student constructor). It is legal to call delete on a NULL pointer, but if the values are uninitialized, you cannot know what will happen if you delete such a pointer.

Comment: @UmNyobe *Exactly* my point in the prior comment. Only the OP knows precisely where and how the addresses loaded into that pointer array are (a) allocated, and (b) owned. Without being privy to that information (aka. design) there is no way to conclusively answer the question.

Comment: @K-ballo - no, I don't think so. I suspect that that's why so many people here want to use pointers for everything: they've had some experience with Java and don't yet grasp that C++ is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the vector owns the students (that is, it is responsible for deleting them), don't use pointers at all (unless you need polymorphism, but you didn't state that in the question so I assume you don't). If you do this, you don't need to explicitly define the dtor, the copy ctor and the copy assignment operator anymore; see the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

```
vector<Student> vectorName;
```

If you don't want the overhead of copying objects when inserting them in the vector, either move them or use `emplace_back`:

```
vectorName.push_back(std::move(student));
vectorName.emplace_back("John", 42);
```

Comment: That will have an overhead of copying the class when pushing it to the vector.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer not if you move it or use `emplace_back`.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer, have you measured the overhead? Is it serious enough to warrant writing code the OP doesn't understand and has to ask the interweb about?  I think simplicity and correctness might trump perceived overhead in this case.

Comment: I understand where you are trying to go, but seeing how the OP says it's homework, chances are he has to deal with the vector of pointers and can't really change the parameters of the question.

Comment: @Fred OP asked for the correct way of doing memory management (see the question). This is the correct way, homework or not.

Comment: The overhead of copying the Student objects is probably negligible. But does it make sense to copy them? Do you want to allow for the possibility that there are two Student objects corresponding to the same student? Probably not. If not, make the class explicitly non-copyable, create the objects on the heap, and manage them with smart pointers.

Comment: @user763305 or just make them non-copyable and *move* them into the vector. Only use `std::shared_ptr` when you really need shared ownership. I can't tell of OP needs it (he didn't say so), but I never needed shared ownership.

Comment: Fred is correct. In no way I should manipulate the structure of definitions.

Comment: @user1656647 In that case, this answer won't help (but don't think storing owning raw pointers in a vector is ever a good idea). I will leave it here for future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

This mainly depends on where a `Student*` references stored. If a `Student*` instance has its personal list of students which are not reference any where else then what you are doing generates many dangling pointers.

When destroying a `std::vector` the destructor on contained objects is implicitly called, this means that if the objects contained are `Student*` then just the space for the pointer is released and you have to manually do what you are doing which is correct **IF AND ONLY IF you don't store the same Student* in more than one collection**.

So to summarize:

- deleting the `Student*` object must be done if the vector contained the only reference to it.
- deleting a `Student*` in a collection will invalidate pointers to it in other collections which will lead to problems
- in the case of shared students you have to find a way to check when there are no more references to it (while destroying a vector) so that you can safely delete it. (see smart pointers, you can also manually count references but that would be reinventing the wheel)

Comment: @user1656647, yes, a `shared_ptr` solves the problem of knowing if you have the only reference deleting the object automatically when there are no more references (but doesn't solve the problem of circular references), and `unique_ptr` solves the problem by only ever allowing one reference. There are other smart pointers, but those two meet the majority of needs.

Comment: In case of circular reference, **smart pointers will not help**. The cycles must be broken down manually... or the ownership transferred.

Answer (score 2):

if you allocated item of `vectorname` with `new Student`, then yes. But you have to remember that after this point any data pointed by a  `vectorName.at(i)` is destroyed, and should not be accessed somewhere else in the program.